# Change model inside a ng-repeat scope from outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater inside of a controller, and each item in the repeater has its own status:

```
<div ng-controller="...">
  <div ng-repeat"...">{{status}}</div>
</div>
```

Now, lets say i want to change this status, if i use `status = 'foo'` inside the repeater it works like a charm, every item in the repeat can have its own status. However, i want to change this status from the controller, since i want to use some ajax calls and such magic. I've searched all the web and asked my good friend google several questions but i cant find any info about how to get to the scope in the repeated item.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49ZFg/7/) simulates my problem, if you click one of the buttons it will change the status of the whole scope to `clicked` and what i'm trying to achieve is to only get the circle next to the button to turn blue. (i know that i can add a value in the list but i have my reasons not do it that way.)

Comment: Try ng-repeat"..." ng-controller="InnerCtrl" from within the InnerCtrl you've got access to all the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the classic case of prototypal inheritance. You can use `this.status` to set status in current scope.

See my fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/BdcuS/

When the method is invoked it is invoked with this set to the current scope. Which is the scope of `ng-repeat`

My answer would not be complete till i link to this wiki page https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes that talks about this.

Comment: Good answer. You'd need to store the reference to the scope for use within the timeout too: http://jsfiddle.net/heQg5/

Answer (score 3):

Each item needs to have its own *unique* status property, rather than one single one attached to your controller, for example:

```
function fooCtrl($scope, $timeout){
    // list is now an array of objects, each of which has an empty status property
    $scope.list = [{status: null}, {status: null}, {status: null}];

    $scope.setStatus = function(item, status){
        // Only update the status of that one property
        item.status = status;

        //Simulate an ajax request
        $timeout(function(){
            item.status = null;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div class="circle {{item.status}}">

    </div>
    <button ng-click="setStatus(item, 'clicked')">click me</button>
</div>
```

[Update jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCFqw/)

Comment: Thanks for this, both you and Chandermani helped me understand scopes better.